# Running Unicorn on a Dedicated Publishing Instance

Tags: unicorn

We would like to move Unicorn from the CM server to instead handle syncs in Production on our Dedicated Publishing Instance. This is because the DP isn't doing a great deal where as the CM has a lot of resource demands on it.

I am aware that if we remove Unicorn from the CM then there will be no content editor warnings anymore about which items are handled in Unicorn. However we are happy to accept this and ensure Content Editors are aware of which items are controlled by Unicorn and should not be edited and which are safe to edit.

Unless I'm missing something, as long as the serialised files are uploaded to the DP instance and Unicorn (and our custom serialisation config) are deployed on the DP server and Master/Core DB access from the DP instance is ok it should be possible to run the sync on the DP instance and then go to the CM server and see the changes.

I can't find anything in the Unicorn docs or blog posts on this so what I'd like to know is if there is anything else I've not considered here at all?

I'd also like to know if there is likely to be a delay on the CM server with seeing the updated/new items (e.g Master db items being cached) after a sync on the DP instance?

**Further info:** Sitecore 8.2 u7. Unicorn 4.0.8

Comment: Mostly, this has nothing to do with Unicorn. You _might_ need to write a custom processor for sync end to force CM to drop its caches, but I don't even think that should be necessary.

Comment: Be aware of the configuration roles however. Some of Unicorn only enables on ContentManagement and Standalone roles.

Comment: Thanks Mark. When you saying nothing to do with Unicorn, do you mean performance-wise Unicorn shouldn't be causing issues and it's other performance issues with the CM that should be the focus?

Comment: Well. Unicorn is passive on a CM until called, assuming its data provider is not active. Running it on a separate server is fine and it mostly has to do with how Sitecore internally handles :remote events that will come into play,.

Comment: Ok thanks. Is there any performance impact with showing Unicorns content editor messages around items controlled by unicorn? I think the impression is this will have some impact on Content Editor load and response time.

Comment: Should't be.You can disable it in Unicorn.UI.config to confirm.